# Is there a way store a range as a value for a column that stores floats

Tags: mysql, database

I have a column in my mysql database which stores a float value like 0.4. The problem is, this value column also sometimes needs to store a range like 0.1-0.4. Right now the column is set to datatype double and I know I could achieve what I want by making the datatype to string and doing my own parsing in my endpoints, however I want to know if there is a more elegant way of achieving what I want. Thanks.

Ex:

```
id  |   name |   value |
1     test1      12.01
2     test2      13.01-15.02
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you need to store or represent a range, which logically represents two values, in a SQL table, then the easiest way to do this is to use two columns.  For example:

```
low | high
0.1 | 0.4
```

Now to find all records within your range, you may simply use `BETWEEN`:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE 0.3 BETWEEN low AND high;
```

**Edit:**

If some of your "ranges" might consist of a single point, then just record the `low` and `high` value as being the same value.

Comment: This. Nothing more complicated than this. Nothing else to it. You got two values? Store two values.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I've thought of this, however my problem is like I said, the value could be just a regular float OR it could be a range. See edited post for example

Comment: @rominoushana A point can be represented by a range whose start and end is the same value.